# ModuleNot FoundError : No module named 'lib'

Tags: python, import

I am trying to understand import mechanism behind python but this piece of code gives error.

Here is my folder structure:

```
import_test
  -calculator
   ..__init__.py
   ..operation.py
  -lib
   ..__init__.py
   ..multiply.py
```

It is working when i ran on PyCharm IDE, but if i run from command line like

```
'py operation.py'(for now windows,for the next phase i will try on raspbian RPi)
```

**i am getting module not found error! Tried many ways from forums on internet but still no progress.**

multiply.py:

```
def multiplier(a,b):
    return a + b
```

operation.py:

```
from lib.multiply import multiplier
print (multiplier(3,4))
```

lib/**init**.py:

```
from .multiply import multiplier
```

This is the output of my running:

```
File "operation.py", line 1, in <module>
    from lib.multiply import multiplier
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

Comment: Try having `__init__.py` in the root directory(`import_test`) as well

Comment: with empty content? @SundeepPidugu

Comment: @mert yes, empty is fine. Python checks for the existence of `__init__.py` (irrespective of whether it has any contents) to determine whether or not something counts as a module.

Comment: Ok. Created empty __init__.py but no change @GreenCloakGuy

Comment: Try to run like this  `python -vv operation.py`  python will print lots of info include all possible places where it's looking for the modules.

Comment: This is  just one of the reasons why python is a joke of a language. These imports.

Answer (score 1):

To go up a directory, to another directory, and back down, almost always requires editing the `sys.path` pycharm tends to do this automatically for a project, without really telling you it did.

using the structure you have in the question this should work:

```
import_test
  -calculator
   ..__init__.py (EMPTY FILE)
   ..operation.py
  -lib
   ..__init__.py (EMPTY FILE)
   ..multiply.py
```

operation.py:

```
import os
import sys

# insert the "import_test" directory into the sys.path
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.abspath(".."))

from lib.multiply import multiplier

print (multiplier(3,4))
```

multiply.py:

```
def multiplier(a,b):
    return a + b
```

Running operation.py returns:

`7`

Comment: Thanks for that useful answer but here is a more efficient way that i found: ````import sys
sys.path.append("..")```` That's all! :)

Comment: @mert The only reason I used `os.path.abspath("..")` is I've seen relative paths not work correctly in linux a few times, yet forcing the relative path to the absolute path worked. But if the straight relative path is working than great!

Comment: @mert Also the `sys.path.insert(1, path)`, is a preference for me, simply because it ensures that any additional items in the path are seen after the path I really want it paying attention too. This way any modules that have the same name will be superseded by the module I told it to look at.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you are starting up your script from calculator directory, so python add's `import_test/calculator` to the sys.path,  but it doesn't know anything about the lib.

You can either follow @tgikal advice and add parent directory to the sys.path but it looks like an ugly hack.  Better way to handle this is to run your script like this

python -m calculator.operation,  you might need to add an empty `__init__.py` file to the import_test directory,  depends on your version of python.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had copied some code from another project that had user built modules in the imports at the top of the code, but I did not copy this user built module to my new project. I found this needed `lib` module folder in the original project and copied it to get rid of the message.